# jQuery function not invoked from window variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, primefaces, applet

I need to show a `primefaces` `dialog` when my `applet` is closed, because there is a `thread` doing some stuff once it's finished i would like to hide the dialog from the page.

In order to do this i have used the liveConnect using `netscape.javascript.JSObject`.
this is working like a charm everything is alright.

The problem is the javascript functions are well invoked, but the dialog.show() function is not invoked.

Here is the code :

```
function doit1() {
             $(window).ready(function() {
                 statusDialog.show();
            });

        }
        ;
function doit2() {
    $(window).ready(function() {
    statusDialog.hide();
            });
        };
window.callJS = function() {
      console.log("we're here 1");
      doit1();
      console.log("its here1");
        };
window.callJS1 = function() {
     console.log("we're here 2");
     doit2();
     console.log("its here2");
        };
```

these methods are called from the applet like this :

```
JSObject window = JSObject.getWindow(this);       
window.call("callJS", null);
//do_some_thread_stuff();
window.call("callJS1", null);
```

And here is what's happening in the console :

```
we're here 1 
its here1 
we're here 2 
its here2
```

So, what i'm really missing and what's preventing the dialog from showing.

**Note :** when i use chrome DevTools console to execute the doit() methods they're working fine but i get the undefined aftermath.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with threads, i was invoking JS methods before `thread.start()`.
I've put the  window.call("callJS", null); inside the thread and it's working fine.